# Finding the hovered asset id from a VS Code extension

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to display a thumbnail when an asset id is being hovered from a VS Code extension.

```js
let disposable = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider(['lua', 'luau'], {
        async provideHover(document, position, token) {
            const range = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position, /rbxassetid:\/\/\d+/);
            const word = document.getText(range);

            const id = /rbxassetid:\/\/(\d+)/.exec(word)?.[1];
            
            console.log(`Found ${id}, fetching thumbnail info...`);
            const response = await fetch(`<roblox-thumbnail-api>`);
            const data = await response.json() as RobloxThumbnailResponse;
            const image = data.data?.[0]?.imageUrl;
            console.log(image);

            const mdString = new vscode.MarkdownString(`Asset: ${id}\n<img src="${image}" height="150px">`);
            mdString.supportHtml = true;
            return new vscode.Hover(mdString);
        }
    });
```

This is working mostly, but hovering over something that doesn't match something like `rbxassetid://1818` will still display a thumbnail.

I'm using this little `luautest.luau` script to test my extension.

```lua
-- some random stuff that isn't using asset ids
for i=1, 10 do
    print(i)
end
print("rbxassetid://1818") -- an asset id
-- some more stuff that isn't using asset ids
for i=10, 1, -1 do
    print(i)
end
print("rbxassetid://7200003285") -- another asset id
-- some more random stuff that isn't using asset ids
for i=1, 10 do
    print(i)
end
```

Hovering over `rbxassetid://1818` works as expected.
[image: hovering over the first asset]
*hovering the string on line 5*

Hovering over the other asset id also works as expected.
[image: hovering over the second asset]
*hovering the string on line 10*

The issue is that hovering over anything else will always display asset `1818`.
[image: hovering over something that isn't an asset]
*hovering `print` on line 8*

I'm not sure how to fix this RegEx so that hovering over something that isn't an asset id doesn't match the first asset id in the file.

Comment: `rbxassetid://1818` matches your regex.

Comment: But how would I make it match *only* if its hovering over the asset id? Hovering other stuff still matches `rbxassetid://1818` and I don't know how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `document.getWordRangeAtPosition()` can return undefined, which seems to cause `document.getText()` to match the entire document. I was able resolve this issue by adding this after the call to `document.getWordRangeAtPosition`.

```js
if (!range) {
    return;
}
```